# Disable removal of whitespace at the end of an empty line in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

If I have this sample code:

```
function foo()
{
    var bar = 1;
    var foo = 1;
    // These two lines will be indented on save,
    // however the following line will have it's indention removed:

    return foo + bar;
}
```

How can I make Sublime Text 2 stop removing the indention on lines only containing whitespace?

If possible I would still like it to remove it from lines which contains other characters than whitespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out that setting `trim_automatic_white_space` to `false` solved my problem.

However it doesn't work when enabling `trim_trailing_white_space_on_save`.

Comment: I had it set in sublime 2 and when installed sublime 3, just lost what option it was. This same option is in v3.

Answer (score 0):

In case you've already lost wanted whitespace-only indented lines, like happened to me by the thousands on save, here is my script to restore indentation to empty lines within indented blocks of code:

https://github.com/phuein/BlockIndentFixer